# Adding data into Mysql database on localhost

Tags: php, android, mysql, localhost, wampserver

i'm trying to create a registration form but the app keeps crashing 
i think it might be the URL form my virtual emulator, i have tried 10.0.2.2 and 10.0.3.2 and i checked virtual box to see which address to use and i got 192.168.79.2 but non of them worked.

here is my **BackgroundTask.java** class

```
 public class BackgroundTask extends  
                  AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Context ctx;
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx){

        this.ctx=ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String method= params[0];
        String reg_url="http://192.168.79.2/webapp/register.php";
       // String login_url="http://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php";

        if(method.equals("register")){
            String names=params[1];
            String user_name=params[2];
            String user_pass=params[3];
            try {
                URL url= new URL(reg_url);
                HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)  

                url.openConnection();
                httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream OS=httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =new BufferedWriter(new   

             OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(names, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                return "Registration success";

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ;
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,"result" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and here is my Register.java Activity

```
public class Register extends Activity {

    EditText ET_NAME, ET_USER_NAME, ET_USER_PASS;
    String name, user_name, user_pass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        ET_NAME=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        ET_USER_NAME=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        ET_USER_PASS=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

    }

    public void userReg(View view){

        name= ET_NAME.getText().toString();
        user_name=ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString();
        user_pass=ET_USER_PASS.getText().toString();

        String method= "register";
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method, name, user_name, user_pass);
        finish();

    }

}
```

and here is my register.php file

```html
<?php
require"init.php";

$names=$_POST["names"];
$user_name=$_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass=$_POST["user_pass"];

$sql_query="insert into info values('$names', '$user_name', '$user_pass');";

if(mysqli_query($con, $sql_query)){

//echo"<h3>Data insertion Success...</h3>";
}
else{
//echo"Data insertion error...".mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: what is your port ? for ex i have http://10.0.2.2:57714 then 57714 is my port and check app in your emulator

Comment: how can i find this port? never tried it before!

Comment: try this: http://10.0.2.2:80/webapp/register.php let me know is it work for you?

Comment: 10.0.3.2 worked i had a problem in my import

Answer (score 0):

## Your Solution

From what I can see, is the first line supposed to be `URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")`? Clearly your PHP form shows `$names=$_POST["names"];`, which means that the POST variable ***should*** be `names`.

If your database is not configured for null variables, it will error out.

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(names, "UTF-8")+"&"+
              URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8")+"&"+
              URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: will thank you for that i fixed it but it crashed anyway
i ran the debugger and it crashed at this line
"httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");"

Comment: @OdeyM.Khalaf What does the debugger say?

Comment: @OdeyM.Khalaf That is strange, could you affix your stack-trace to the end of your post?

Comment: i think this is what's wrong i gave you the wrong message :

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Comment: Ok, can you affix your imports? I think you *may* have imported the wrong package but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Call the async Task as

```
ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
                        params.add(name);
                        params.add(userId);
                        params.add(passw);
                        new registerTask().execute(params);
```

Try This:

```
 public class registerTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progress1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... passing) {
                ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.79.2/webapp/register.php");
                String responses = null;
                ArrayList<String> data = passing[0];
                String name = data.get(0);
                String uid = data.get(1);
                String passw = data.get(2);
                int ik;
                try {
                    //add data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("names", name));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", uid));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_pass", passw));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    //execute http post
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
//You will get the response from server in response
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                return "Success"; //return result
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
            }
        }
```

I dont know know whether i missed anything....
Just try this..

Answer (score 0):

thank you @lefsFlare i had a problem in my import

i changed from : `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;`
to:  `java.net.HttpURLConnection;`